How to parse XML lists with Jackson without a special case for 1 element lists?
I would like to use Jackson JsonNode to parse XML files that have this type of structures very often:
    <list>
        <element>
            <a>value 1a</a>
            <b>value 1b</b>
        </element>
        <element>
            <a>value 2a</a>
            <b>value 2b</b>
        </element>
    </list>

        

Sometimes however the same lists only contain 1 element, like this one:
    <list>
        <element>
            <a>value a</a>
            <b>value b</b>
        </element>
    </list>

        

The problem that I face when using JsonNode is that JsonNode.get("element") returns an ArrayNode for the first XML but an ObjectNode for the second XML.  I know that this can be workarounded with this line:
elements = elements.isArray() ? elements : new XmlMapper().createArrayNode().add(elements);

but I would like to use a more straightforward solution, like using a JsonNode method that always returned an ArrayNode.  Something like JsonNode.getArray("element") would be perfect.
Do you know if this can be accomplished with Jackson?
This is the full code:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String xmlExample1 = """
            <list>
                <element>
                    <a>value 1a</a>
                    <b>value 1b</b>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <a>value 2a</a>
                    <b>value 2b</b>
                </element>
            </list>
        """;

        String xmlExample2 = """
            <list>
                <element>
                    <a>value a</a>
                    <b>value b</b>
                </element>
            </list>
        """;

        processXml(xmlExample1);
        processXml(xmlExample2);
    }

    private static final XmlMapper XM = new XmlMapper();

    private static void processXml(String xml) throws IOException {
        JsonNode rootNode = XM.readTree(xml);

        JsonNode elements = rootNode.get("element");

        elements = elements.isArray() ? elements : XM.createArrayNode().add(elements);

        for (JsonNode element : elements) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + element.get("a").asText());
        }
    }
}


I don't think there is a nice way.
You would need to do a field.isArray()
